# socket.io JWT with PHP

Tags: socket.io, jwt

I am running a php website(www.mywebsite.com). Now I would like to add a real-time chat function so users can chat with others.

I decided to run node.js and socket.io in another server separating from web server(chat.mywebsite.com).

Users who wish to use chat function have to log in through www.mywebsite.com. After login, they will be sent to a chat page (www.mywebsite.com/chat). So on this page the client must post a request to web server for a JWT and use this JWT to authenticate in socket.io.

My question is: if the JWT is stolen by someone else, and pass the JWT to socket.io, it will definitely fake the server that the user is authenticated. So is this approach correct or can you suggest another method for my situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has access for a JWT token - they basically hijacked his session, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

As long as you don't have XSS's or other vulns on your website, it shouldn't be something you should worry about.

just make sure that the socket.io does auth the user by using the jwt token before letting him send/recieve messages.